# SQL Server - T-SQL - why CAST( 0.26 AS REAL) returns 0.25999999046325684

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone explain why in SQL Server / T-SQL, this query

```
SELECT CAST(0.26 AS REAL)
```

returns

```
0,25999999046325684
```

and this query

```
SELECT CAST(0.27 AS REAL)
```

returns

```
0,27000001072883606
```

but this one

```
SELECT CAST(0.25 AS REAL)
```

returns 0,25

When I use datatype `MONEY` instead of `REAL` or `FLOAT`, everything is fine, but I want to learn why this happens...

Comment: You need to learn about fixed versus floating point number representations.  I would suggest starting with Wikipedia or some other source.

Comment: Dude i tried to google but i do not found any of nice sources to study why this happens to me , but thx

Comment: it's still weird that doing just that `CAST` it gives a different result (with no other operations going on), I can't replicate that behavior in any database

Comment: Try [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/floating-point-numbers) or [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/the-practical-problems-of-determining-equality-and-equivalence-in-sql/) found by Googling "t-sql fixed versus floating point number representations" but cannot replicate your first result.